# apsrev4-1 bibliography style: only show the starting page

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, revtex

See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[secnumarabic,amssymb, nobibnotes, aps, pre, twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\newcommand{\revtex}{REV\TeX\ }
\newcommand{\classoption}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\macro}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}
\newcommand{\m}[1]{\macro{#1}}
\newcommand{\env}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

hey \cite{toral_fokker-planck_2003}

\bibliography{./ex}

\end{document}
```

And in my `ex.bib` (just an example):

```
@inproceedings{toral_fokker-planck_2003,
title = {A Fokker-Planck description for Parrondo's games},
volume = {5114},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1117/12.490173},
doi = {10.1117/12.490173},
abstract = {We discuss in detail two recently proposed relations between the Parrondo's games and the Fokker-Planck equation describing the flashing ratchet as the overdamped motion of a particle in a potential landscape. In both cases it is possible to relate exactly the probabilities of the games to the potential in which the overdamped particle moves. We will discuss under which conditions current-less potentials correspond to fair games and vie versa.},
urldate = {2013-12-27},
booktitle = {Proc. {SPIE}},
author = {Toral, Raul and Amengual, Pau and Mangioni, Sergio},
year = {2003},
pages = {309--317}
}
```

The output of the reference list is something like: R. Toral, P. Amengual, and S. Mangioni, in Proc. SPIE, Vol. 5114 (2003) pp. 309–317.

In journals like Physical Review E, a reference item only shows `309` instead of `pp. 309-137`. My question is, is there a way to make latex only show the first page number without having to manually edit the .bib file?